# Does declaring a React.memo inside another functional component provide the memoization performance as it is intended?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Lately I've been thinking about ways to memoize some children components of a functional component, based on [Dmitri's how to use React.memo wisely](https://dmitripavlutin.com/use-react-memo-wisely/). These children components may / may not be using some props from the main component.

Let the component be written like so:

```js
export const MainComponent = ({a, b}) => {
  const AComponent = React.memo(() => <p>This is the string of {a}</p>)

  return (
    <div>
      <AComponent />
      <p>This is the string of {b}</p>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Say the `MainComponent` is re-rendered several times over its lifecycle in a parent component.

```js
const App = () => {
  const [a, setA] = useState(0); // a is update only when a button is pressed
  const [b, setB] = useState(0); // b is updated every 1 second

  const onClick = () => setA(a => a + 1);

  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => setB(b => b + 1, 1000);
    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <MainComponent a={a.toString()} b={b.toString()} />
      <button onClick={onClick}>increment a</button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

I understand that as states `a` and `b` in the `App` are updated, it needs to be re-rendered, which in turn has to re-render the `MainComponent` which depends on `a` and `b`.

There are 2 questions:

1. When the `interval` updates `b` in `App`, `a` is not updated at all, so when the `MainComponent` re-renders, should it use the memoized `AComponent`, not paying the cost of rendering?
2. I do know that when the button is pressed, `a` in `App` is updated, which makes `MainComponent` re-render; the `AComponent` cannot use the memoized version, so it needs to pay the cost of rendering over again, but after that it becomes memoized, ready for the next re-render of `MainComponent`. Am I correct to say, while `b` is not updated during this render cycle, the `<p>This is the string of {b}</p>` (not memoized) is re-rendered, paying the cost of rendering?

---

Am I using React's memo correctly? Which of these alternatives would be better? Are they functionally the same?

1. React.memo

```js
const AComponent = React.memo(props => <p>This is the string of {props.a}</p>)
```

2. React.useMemo

```js
const aComponent = React.useMemo(() => <p>This is the string of {a}</>, [a])

// then use it like
return <>{ aComponent }</>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a) Memoizing is always faster in my tests (despite some blog posts saying otherwise). Having said that you're not going to see any noticeable gains unless you have a particularly heavy component, or the component is rendering lots of children. It could also save you from loosing focus if you're typing and that input gets re-rendered because the parent does.

b) In short none of them will work, `React.memo` has to sit outside the render function, it's not part of the "magic" `use` hook functions which maintain references. You have to use `useMemo` for inside render. Here's an example: The components which don't re-render every second are `CComponent` and `DComponent`:

```js
const CComponent = React.memo(({ count }) => (
  <p>Not re-rendered every second: {count}</p>
));

const MainComponent = (props) => {
  const AComponent = React.memo(() => (
    <p>Re-render when parent does: {props.count}</p>
  ));

  const BComponent = React.memo(({ count }) => (
    <p>Re-render when parent does: {count}</p>
  ));
  
  const DComponent = React.useMemo(() => (
    <p>Not re-rendered every second: {props.count}</p>
  ), [props.count]);

  return (
    <div>
      <AComponent />
      <BComponent count={props.count} />
      <CComponent count={props.count} />
      {DComponent}
      <p>parent count: {props.count}</p>
      <p>parent anotherCounter: {props.anotherCounter}</p>
    </div>
  );
};

function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = React.useState(0);
  const [anotherCounter, setAnotherCounter] = React.useState(100);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const h = setInterval(() => {
      setCount((c) => c + 1);
    }, 6000);
    const h2 = setInterval(() => {
      setAnotherCounter((c) => c + 1);
    }, 1000);
    return () => {
      clearInterval(h);
      clearInterval(h2);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <MainComponent count={count} anotherCounter={anotherCounter} />
    </div>
  );
}


ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('#container'));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the insights. It was my mistake to assume that `React.memo` can be used within a functional component's render, but I'm glad that `useMemo` actually allows doing that.

Comment: "`React.memo` has to sit outside the render function" @Dominic citation needed. How did you come to this conclusion? The docs certainly only show examples of using `React.memo` outside the render function, but I haven't found anything stating it "has to".

Answer (score 0):

I used the memo in a little experiment, I upload the pictures maybe it will be useful.

Title.js:

[image: title.js description]

App.js:

[image: app.js description]

Comment: It's a good effort, but it doesn't really answer any of the questions.